# How to use map quest geocoding api in iPhone app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mapquest

I have to use the map quest geocoding api to show the user location with annotations. After researching, its observes that map quest developed [iOS SDK](https://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/featured/apple-ios-maps-api) in 2012. Now a day, all the link pointing to the map quest api for iPhone is broken. And according to the [forum discussion](https://developer.mapquest.com/forum/where-download-ios-sdk), they plan to release it on next year. Anyone used this before ? Please suggest.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you describe your requirements in a little more detail? Is using MapQuest a firm requirement because there are a number of other SDKs that are much more mature.

If you can't wait for their SDK you could mimic the functionality fairly simply using NSURLSession/NSJSONSerialization.

Comment: I have to check the performance and look of mapquest api map for iPhone app.   how they render on map ? etc. If you have any other map for this please don't hesitate to share.thnx.

Comment: Your best bet option would be to use Apple Maps. It's free and obviously much more tightly integrated with the Apple SDKs. [link]https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/UsingGeocoders/UsingGeocoders.html